# Problems with reading a 8bit grayscale bmp file in c

Tags: c

I want to read a 8 bit grayscale bmp file, reconstruct it's pixel matrix, then process it with sobel operator. However program can not construct pixel matrix, it divides the original pitcure blocks. When I run the program like that; 
**./sobel cube.bmp output.bmp processed.bmp output.txt**
cube.bmp is the input
output.bmp is the output of constructed pixel matrix.
proccessed.bmp is the output of processed with sobel operator.
 
[Code and Sample photos](http://web.itu.edu.tr/~kioutsovkm)

Comment: I suspect the answer lies in the output of `Print`, which is the only thing you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of comments:

Your *processed.bmp* has the look of a bitmap written with an incorrect row size or pixel size. You can tell that, because each row is horizontally shifted.

You are processing grayscale bitmaps, but you are reading and writing pixels as though they have RGB components, i.e.:

```
pixelArray[i][j].red = pixel.red;
pixelArray[i][j].green = pixel.green;
pixelArray[i][j].blue = pixel.blue;
```

A grayscale pixel is just a single 8-bit value.

Comment: I've tried the PIXEL struct with only one unsigned char value. Nothing changes, always same result

Comment: Accessing RGB pixels may not be your only problem, but it is a problem. You should also look at your read/write loops - make sure you're not going off the end of one of your allocated arrays. Incidentally, you might consider allocating all of your arrays as a single pointer rather than an array of individually allocated pointers.

Comment: Additionally, you may also try simply reading the bitmap and outputting the same bitmap. Once that's working, then go back and add the code to apply the Sobel operator.

Comment: How nobody haven seen it ?? I've found the bug. The line on read/write loop fseek(filePtr, sizeof(PIXEL), SEEK_CUR); moves the file pointer one byte unnecessary at every step. I've deleted the line, and now it creates the output exactly same with input. Now sobel operator have problems to handle it. Thansk for answers

Answer (score 2):

possibly not the answer you are looking for but, take a look at openCV.

Assuming your interest is in the image processing steps not specifically BMP manipulation, this library takes care of all the file i/o, display etc for you. It also has a good sobel filter.

Comment: Using OpenCV here seems like using a Saturn rocket to climb a tree.

Comment: @seth - true but if the OP is interested in image filters then messing around with BMP header alignments is like designing your own ladder to climb a tree ;-)